# Datagridview - fill row from Combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have set a `combobox` to be visible in `column1` of my `Datagridview`. Now I'm trying to fill same row of `Datagridview` where Combobox appears, from `Combobox_Key_Down` event. This is my code for showing combobox:

```
Private Sub My_DGV_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles MY_DGV.CellMouseClick

 If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

   With My_DGV
     If .Columns(.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ColumnIndex).Name = "Column1" Then
        .CurrentCell = .Rows(.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
        Show_Combobox(.CurrentRow.Index, .CurrentCell.ColumnIndex) 'function that shows my Combobox in that cells
        Combo.Visible = True

     Else
        Combo.Visible = False
     End If
   End With
 End If

End Sub
```

I tried many things, but I don't know how to determine in which row Combobox appears and how give that `Datagridview` row my `Combobox` values. Someone please give me a clue of what should I do. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean that all rows have a `combobox ` in `column1` and you want to determinate in which row the `combobox` is expanded?

Comment: Are you still struggling with how to portray/edit a m:m association table?

Comment: @Plutonix, yes:). But I have managed to do something today, I think It might actually work. I will post an answer If I get It right, tommorow.

Comment: @Mech_Engineer, yes. But I allready determinate using .SelectedCells(0).RowIndex. I filled all row using that also. I just need to sort updating dataset and DB insert now. I will post an answer tommorow, If I will manage It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your approach is that the DGV can have only one `DataSource`: it can either show the m:m association table *or* the related elements.  If you include columns from one of the tables into the query for display, the table becomes non updatable and users can be confused why they cannot edit something they can see.  It seems of little value they way you describe it, since they cannot see the detail data until *after* they make a selection.

Next, it requires another datatable to supply the details for CboColB. Since you want the DGV bound to a `DataTable` easy updates, you end up having to poke data into cells over and over.

Finally, consider what the user is confronted with.  Using a Country table (200+ countries/locales with ISO code and name) and a list of flag colors, a table for CountryFlagColors will have hundreds and hundreds of rows (at just 2 colors per flag).

A better display might be to filter the `m:m` table (`flagcolor`) to a selected item so the user is only confronted with the data subset they are currently interested in:

[image]

The datatable used in the DGV is built from the m:m table:

- The Country column is hidden.
- When they choose from the CBO at the top, that is used as a RowFilter to limit the rows to the relevant ones.
- In the `RowValidating` event, *when the country cell is DBNull*, copy the `SelectedValue` from the country combo to the DGV cell to fill in the blank

  - I would probably really make the user click a button and manually add a row so I could seed the country value then rather than depend on events.
- It uses a DataAdapter and after adding X number of flag definitions, `da.Update(dtFlagColors)` applies/saves all the changes.

Ok, so that provides the core functionality to assign N color selections to define the flag colors for a country.  The missing element is the 'details' for the Color item.

I added a meaningless int and string item to the Color table, one way to display these would be to create an alias in the SQL with the important details.  Displaying them as discrete elements can either make the query non updatable or invites the user to edit things they cannot edit here.  My silly SQL:

```
"SELECT Id, Name, Concat(Name , ' (' , intItem , ' ' , stritem,')') As Info from FColor"
```

Then use 'Info' as the display member on the CBO column in the dgv:

```
dc = DirectCast(dgvCF.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
dc.DataSource = dtFlagColors
dc.DisplayMember = "info"
dc.ValueMember = "id"
dgvCF.DataSource = dtSample
```

The combo column has its own datasource of course, in order to display one thing and use another for as the Value to give back to you.  Result (the values are silly):

[image]

It is not exactly what you want, but comes close and is much simpler.  It also requires almost no code for driving the associative entity.  Another alternative would be to use a DGV as the second picker so you can show the extended data and manually add rows to a DGV:

[image]

If you set the dropdown style to Nothing, it looks like a text column.

Comment: thanks for this. I'm not sure If i understand everything you wrote though....I think my problem is simmilar but still different - in m:m table I have ID_Table1, ID_Table2 and a field Validity. And User wants to see in Datagrid 3 fields from Table1 (I'm getting this via ID_Table1) + field Validity which is basically the only field that can be changed in Datagrid. So, what I do is to display some data for related table to user with field Validity which can be edited. All other fields all filled from Combobox, but they are just bound to Dataset, I do all Inserts and Updates manually.

Comment: iI give up on this one, you are right, It can't be done like I planned. Though I almost got It working - updates worked fine, doing inserts also. But after I allready inserted  and wanted to update a row, all rows were updated. I will try your suggestion, users will need to accept It.